# How do you add a promise to the flow control queue using protractor?

Tags: angularjs, promise, protractor, flow-control

In my test I am calling and outside library to seed data into our backend before running some ui tests using protractor.

```
'use strict'

var dataBuilder = require('data_builder.js');

describe('test', function () {
  var testData = {
    name: 'foo',
    title: 'bar',
    ...
  };

  beforeEach(function () {
    //create test data on the backend
    dataBuilder.create(testData).then(function (id) {
      testData.id = id.id;
    });
  });



  it('test something', function () {
    ...
  });
```

As such the promise returned by the dataBuilder isn't resolved before the it() actually finishes. How can I add the promise returned by the dataBuilder into webDriver's flow control?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Protractor exposes WebDriverJS promises on the protractor object so you could use either the `flow.await` method or create a new promise and use `flow.execute`.

The former could be achieved something like:

```
flow = protractor.promise.controlFlow()

flow.await(dataBuilder.create(testData)).then( function(id) {
    testData.id = id.id;
})
```

And you can see an example of the latter in this [blog post](http://squirrel.pl/blog/2014/01/15/direct-server-http-calls-in-protractor/).

This could be done in the `it` function itself or if this is common to all your tests consider placing it in the `onPrepare` function of your protractor config.

Comment: I used this approach except I used the `browser.controlFlow().await(...)` shorthand that protractor now supports, works great!

Answer (score 12):

In my protractor tests I add something into webDriver's flow control using the following pattern. If one creates and returns a promise from these "various statements", the promise will be correctly inserted into the control flow.

```
browser.controlFlow().execute(function() {
    // various statements
});
```

Comment: Good answer, but you should make it clear that one can create and return a promise from these "various statements" that will be correctly inserted into the control flow

Answer (score 2):

In this specific case, you could use the `done` callback in the `beforeEach` like this:

```
beforeEach(function (done) {
   dataBuilder
      .create(testData)
      .then(function (id) {
         testData.id = id.id;
      })
      .finally(done);
});
```

Accepting a `done` callback parameter indicates that the setup is asynchronous.

Answer (score 1):

I never remember the syntax, so I use a `hack` of sort that is easier to remember since it relies on the way promise behaves (so basically you can use this in every promise based system)

```
browser.sleep(1).then(()=> {
  return someAsyncPromiseAction();
})
```

Another thing you could do is simply rely on the action before it. So if you, for example, just clicked a button it will look like this

```
$(' ... ').click().then( () => { return someAsync(); })
```

While this doesn't add a promise to the flow control, you still get the same result.