# protractor and order of execution

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, protractor

Having trouble to understand how exactly Protractor order of execution works..

If I am having `PageObject:InvitePage`

And order of execution is defined like this:

```
InvitePage.EnterUsername()
InvitePage.EnterPassword()
InvitePage.EnterEmail()
InvitePage.Invite();
InviteHelper.waitForEmail()
browser.go(invitationUrl)
...
expect(somecondition)
```

All page methods are returning protractor promise(for example browser.sendKeys for entering the password)
waitForEmail also returns the promise that I have created using:

```
protractor.promise.defer()
```

Problem is that `waitForEmail` get executed first and methods after it don't wait for `waitForEmail` to finish, which I expected to be true by creating the promise using protractor method...anyway I found solution to it and it looks something like this:

```
lastMethodBeforeWaitForEmail.then(function(){
    browser.driver.wait(InvitationHelper.waitForEmail(userEmail))
       .then(function(recievedUrl){
         ...
         //methods that I want after
        expect(someCondition)
    });
  });
```

Pretty ugly don't you think?

Is there a way to do this one more nicely, any suggestions?
And which part around async nature of protractor I didn't get? Am I missing something?

**getInvitationEmail**

```
var getInvitationEmail = function (emailAddress){
var deferred = protractor.promise.defer();
mailbox.getEmailsByRecipient(emailAddress, function(err, emails) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('>Fetch email - call rejected');
    deferred.reject(err);
  }else{
    console.log('>Email service fetched.')
    deferred.fulfill(emails);
  }
});

return deferred.promise;
```

};

and then **waitForEmail**

```
this.waitForEmail = function(email){
var deferred = protractor.promise.defer();
var timeout;
var interval = 3000;
var timePassed = 0;

var recursive = function () {
  var message = '>Checking for invitational email';
  if(timePassed>0) {
    message = message + ":" + timePassed/1000 + "s";
  }
  console.log(message);
  timePassed += interval;

  getInvitationEmail(email).then(function(data){
    if(data.length>0){
      var loginUrl = data[0].html.links[0].href;
      if(interval) clearTimeout(timeout);
      console.log(">Email retrieved.Fetching stopped.")
      deferred.fulfill(loginUrl);
    }else{
      console.log(">Still no email.");
    }
  });

  timeout = setTimeout(recursive,interval);
};

recursive();

return deferred.promise;
```

};

Answer (score 3):

In Protractor/WebDriverJS, there is that special mechanism called [Control Flow](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/control-flow.md), which is basically a *queue of promises*. If you have a "custom" promise, in order for it to be in the queue, you need to [put it there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24564489/how-do-you-add-a-promise-to-the-flow-control-queue-using-protractor):

```
flow = protractor.promise.controlFlow();
flow.await(InviteHelper.waitForEmail());
```

Or:

```
browser.controlFlow().wait(InviteHelper.waitForEmail());
```

Comment: @Marko alright, could you please show what is inside the function?

Comment: I have edited the question, added waitForEmail method

Comment: @Marko interesting, I have a similar use case in one of the projects. We have [this `getLastEmail` function](https://gist.github.com/alecxe/9f9c86901d121abf83735ddbcbc70119) and using it via `browser.controlFlow().wait(helpers.getLastEmail("topic")).then(function (email) { ... });`..works for us. Could you check if may be `setTimeout()` is what causing problems here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One question and one remark.

- Shouldn't you put other methods in the ControlFlow if you want to control the execution flow?
- JavaScript engines add `;` at the end of commands when needed, but it is always better to put them yourself.

Comment: 1) they are already in the flow, each of them returning protractor.promise, for example browser.sendKeys or element(by.model(...))
2) I have disabled atom plugin that was warning me when I skip ; :D

Answer (score 0):

In `waitForEmail` you have defined a promise, but you need to insert it into the controlFlow. As you may know, all of the normal webdriver actions `click(), getText(), etc` already know how to execute in the right order so you don't have to chain all your promises with `.then` every time.

```
... the bottom of your function should look like this
recursive();
return browser.controlFlow().execute(function() {
    return deferred.promise;
});
```

Your ugly solution `lastMethodBeforeWaitForEmail.then(function() ...` works because it is one way to make sure the `waitForEmail` promise is executed in the right order, but the above code is the prettiness that you are looking for.