# Protractor error on Angular page testing: A Jasmine spec timed out. Resetting the WebDriver Control Flow

Tags: angular, jasmine, protractor, automated-tests, e2e-testing

When I use `browser.get` in my specs I have this error with

```
ScriptTimeoutError: Timed out waiting for asynchronous Angular tasks to 
finish after 11 seconds. This may be because the current page is not an 
Angular application. Please see the FAQ for more details: 
https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md#waiting- 
for-angular While waiting for element with locator - Locator: By(css 
selector, [class="loading ng-scope ng-isolate-scope"]).`
```

Webdriver is the latest version

- I have to use angular elements in my spec but I tried to change
  `browser.ignoreSynchronization` to `true` before `browser.get(link)` and changed to `false` after getting page. Nothing changed. I also tried using `browser.driver.get(link)` instead of `browser.get(link)`. Increased 
  `allScriptsTimeout: 110000, 
  getPageTimeout: 110000, 
  defaultTimeoutInterval: 600000`

What should I do not to take this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is likely an issue with flow control, [This stackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24564489/how-do-you-add-a-promise-to-the-flow-control-queue-using-protractor) has some good info on flow control.

One of the ways to get around this:

```
flow = protractor.promise.controlFlow();
flow.execute(function(){
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    browser.get(link);
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
});
```